# Should question titles and tags contain version numbers if they are important?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question which I wanted to specifically ask against a specific version of TFS - in my case TFS 2017, and, as such, placed the version number inside the question title.

I did this very methodically knowing full well that previous versions of TFS would not be pertinent to the question.

Another user decided to edit the title and removed the 2017 and instead added the TFS2017 tag. This was AFTER he'd asked me which version of TFS I was targeting (at which point I said 2017, as per the title). Ergo having the version in the title was important, even to him!

My Original title was **Set a Default branch on a TFS 2017 Hosted Repository**

It was changed by another user to **Set a Default branch on a TFS Hosted Repository**

Is this something that should be allowed?

I was very clear I needed to target the latest and greatest version of TFS here and that, since API's vary between versions, the version number was ***very*** important.

Comment: Obligatory "that's not a mod"

Comment: OK, whatever, it was still someone with the powers to change titles, hence the question!

Comment: The user who edited *added* the [tfs2017] tag, [by the looks of it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42179984/revisions); according to the revision history, you never used the [tfs2017] tag when posting.

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot. Apparently I didn't. Please shoot me.... :) Still, the version number in the title WAS important.

Comment: No idea why they'd remove the version number from the title though. Sure the version is now reflected in the tags, but that shouldn't be at the cost of making the title *more ambiguous*.

Comment: My point indeed.

Comment: Unsure why the vote to close. As per the help center "Meta is for...

...Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other about Stack Overflow (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)" ergo it's not 'Off topic' since I'm asking about the policies and decisions acceptable within SO.

Comment: Found this from BoltClock a little under 2 years ago: "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title." At that point, I wouldn't consider them "tags" so much as "keywords". You often need keywords in order to write a clear and concise title. Removing keywords from a title effectively makes it worse.

Would seem to support my position.

Comment: Looks like you edited the version back into the title... problem solved? People are "allowed to" (i.e., not prevented from) make any edits to the question they want, especially after 2000 rep. You can make edits to reverse that, or even rollback your question to its previous state. If the user edits your question again, flag your question for moderator attention.

Comment: And that's basically answered my question! So, yes they can. Should they is a different story though... :) Thanks all!

Comment: do note you can ping editors in a comment. It won't autocomplete but does work. So you could have typed a comment under your question:  *hey @MrHinsh I see you edited my title but I'm afraid that it attracts the wrong audience and therefor answers to my question. Can you elaborate why you removed the year?* When stuff get heated after that Meta is the next step. But we expect it would be resolved peacefully....

Comment: Thanks @rene! I appreciate the info.